# Protractor to select using css for onclick()

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, protractor, automated-tests

I am not able to click this or is there any alternative ways to lead this click:

```
element(by.css('[onclick="ShowApprovalPendingDetils("SQ","05")"]')).click();
```

here is the html DOM

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <a class="btn btn-app" style="width: 90%;" onclick="ShowApprovalPendingDetils('SQ','05')">
    <span class="badge bg-green">3</span>
    Sales Quotation
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo: Your quotes don't match.

Comment: @Quentin i have tried this too `element(by.css("[onclick='ShowApprovalPendingDetils('SQ','05')']")).click();`

Comment: Start → 'ShowApprovalPendingDetils(' ← End. Think about what quotes mean in context.

Comment: @Quentin I tried this too `element(by.css("[onclick='ShowApprovalPendingDetils("SQ","05")']")).click();` i too didnt worked for me

Comment: Start →  "[onclick='ShowApprovalPendingDetils(" ← End

Comment: @Quentin how it will get ends there while its inside single quote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183783/discussion-between-rao-and-quentin).

Comment: Because the parser doesn't treat "There is an open single quote" as a blocker for "There is a double quote character which closes the existing double quoted thing"

Comment: @Quentin okay i am using onlclick() just because the parameter in it makes it unique as you can see  `("SQ")`

Comment: @Quentin or is there anyway i can identify those parameter directly

Comment: You need to learn about escaping.

Comment: "[onclick='ShowApprovalPendingDetils(\"SQ\",\"05"\)'] please do check this @Quentin

Comment: What happens when you run this spec? Does it throw an error "element not found"?

Comment: if it cant escape the quotes the spec won't run but if it escapes then it does not identifies the locator

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov it skips this portion

Comment: It can't skip anything. It either throws an error 'element not found', or if it sees the element it clicks but nothing happens. Try click like this `browser.executeScript(
   "arguments[0].click();", element(by.css('[onclick=\"ShowApprovalPendingDetils(\"SQ\",\"05\")\"]')).getWebElement()))`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and just add an `id` attribute to this element and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
$('[onclick=ShowApprovalPendingDetils("SQ","05")]')
```

if still failing then

```
$('[onclick*=ShowApprovalPendingDetils]')
```

and if still fail then try to add some wait ( element might taking some more time to load)

Comment: using `xpath` it works but i was trying to select it using methods `parameter`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
element(by.css('a[onclick="ShowApprovalPendingDetils("SQ","05")"]')).click();
```

Or

```
element(by.linkText('Sales Quotation')
```

Or

```
element(by.cssContainingText('a.btn.btn-app','Sales Quotation')
```